# regular expression match digit and characters

Tags: regex, character, digit

How can I create a regex expression that will match only characters and numbers?

this regex matched width digit:
`/\D/g`

how can add characters like `-` , `_` , `*` and etc to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To match Only letter and numbers,

```
[A-Za-z0-9]
```

Add the characters you want into the above character class to match also that specific characters.

```
[A-Za-z0-9_*-]
```

You could reduce the above regex to,

```
[\w*-]
```

Comment: i want match character, no letter

Comment: Which are all the possible characters, you want to match?

Comment: Your first two variants wouldn't catch legit characters such as `Üあ` or [other numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numerals). The third variant does, tho.